# Nest.js CLI not found in Docker multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nest

I'm trying to set up a multi-stage Docker build for my Node.js and Nest.js application. The Dockerfile includes installing dependencies, building the application, and running it. However, I'm encountering an issue with the `npm run build` command in the production stage of the Dockerfile.

Here's a simplified version of my Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
# Use node base image with tag 18-slim
FROM node:18-slim as base

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable to production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Create app directory and set permissions
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R node:node /app

# Switch to non-root user
USER node

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force

# Set PATH environment variable in dev stage
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Copy source code
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Development stage
FROM base as dev

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable to development
ENV NODE_ENV=development

# Command to run development server
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

# Production stage
FROM base as prod

# Build production code
RUN npm run build

# Command to run production server
CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
sh: 1: nest: not found
```

It seems that the Nest.js CLI is not available in the PATH during the production build, even though it's installed as a dev dependency in my package.json.

```
#11 [prod 1/2] RUN ls /app/node_modules/.bin
#11 0.152 acorn
#11 0.152 color-support
#11 0.152 highlight
#11 0.152 js-yaml
#11 0.152 mime
#11 0.152 mkdirp
#11 0.152 node-pre-gyp
#11 0.152 nopt
#11 0.152 opencollective
#11 0.152 semver
#11 0.152 sha.js
#11 0.152 ts-node
#11 0.152 ts-node-cwd
#11 0.152 ts-node-esm
#11 0.152 ts-node-script
#11 0.152 ts-node-transpile-only
#11 0.152 ts-script
#11 0.152 tsc
#11 0.152 tsserver
#11 0.152 typeorm
#11 0.152 typeorm-ts-node-commonjs
#11 0.152 typeorm-ts-node-esm
#11 0.152 uuid
#11 DONE 0.2s
```

How can I ensure that the Nest.js CLI is available in the PATH during the production build in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

###### Rev2

The following instruction in `base` stage renders `/app/node_modules/.bin/nest` unavailable.

```docker
# Set NODE_ENV environment variable to production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
```

But in the current configuration of Dockerfile, because `base` stage is meant for both `dev` and `prod`, including dev dependencies will not sit well for `prod` stage.

Now, I suggest the following to remedy the situation:

- Remove `ENV NODE_ENV=production` and `RUN npm ci` from `base` stage, making this stage free from preparing dev/prod dependencies.
- Put `ENV NODE_ENV=development` and `RUN npm ci` to `dev` stage.
- Put `ENV NODE_ENV=production` and `RUN npm ci` to `prod` stage.

Docker has a nice Dockerfile example on this matter.

https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/develop/#update-your-dockerfile-for-development

###### Rev1

See if changing `/dev/node_modules/.bin` to `/app/node_modules/.bin` resolves the issue.

---

At `base` stage, instruction [`WORKDIR /app`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#workdir) set the working directory for the following instructions like `RUN` to be performed at `/app`, so that following
instruction `RUN npm install` creates `/app/node_modules`.

But later on, at `dev` and `prod` stage, instructions `ENV PATH` include a path `/dev/node_modules/.bin`, which contradicts the setup in `base` stage.

Comment: Tried but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your project layout looks like, but suppose that it's simple like this:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

The following will work and has minimal changes relative to your current setup.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-slim as base

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R node:node /app

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# STAGE: DEV ------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM base as dev

ENV NODE_ENV=development

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

# STAGE: prod -----------------------------------------------------------------

FROM base as prod

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node dist/main.js",
      "start:dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
      "build": "webpack"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "@nestjs/cli": "10.3.2",
      "webpack-cli": "5.1.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    }
  }
```